# MySQL update based on select

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update

```
SELECT 
   table_1.id, 
   (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table_2 WHERE table_1.id = table_2.bid) AS sum_total 
FROM table_1 
WHERE table_1.total!=0
```

I need to update `table_1.total` so that it would equal with `sum_total`.

Any adivce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
update table_1 as t1 left join (select SUM(amount) as totalamount ,id FROM table_1 group by id) as t2 on t1.id =t2.id 
 set  t1.total=t2.totalamount
```

Please do needful changes.

Comment: really not at this time. but I have done similar queries in my work.Let me dig at update if any change

Comment: can we use same table as target name in FROM clause during update???? please take a look at.

Comment: i changed my SELECT query because there were some mistakse. there's two tables

Answer (score 2):

This simple query should work very well.

```
UPDATE 
   table_1 
SET 
   table_1.total = (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table_2 WHERE table_1.id = table_2.bid) 
WHERE table_1.total!=0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you:

```
UPDATE table_1 set total = (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table_1 WHERE table_1.id = table_1.bid) AS sum_total)
```

Comment: not quite, i just updated my base Select query - had two mistakes.